# How does more than one byte value is translated?

Tags: c++, windows, x86

A character `char` maybe of size one byte but when it comes to four bytes value e.g `int` , how does the cpu differ it from an integer instead of four characters per byte?

Comment: I think the question is something along the lines of "How does a CPU know the difference between an int (4 bytes) and 4 chars (4 bytes)?" But I could be way off.

Comment: That, or how does a system represent the types in question...

Comment: The CPU doesn't care.  In the old days, when FORTRAN didn't have a character variable type, we used EQUIVALENCE to map integer arrays into character strings.

Comment: This is effectively a general computer-science question and doesn't really depend on language or platform.

Answer (score 4):

The CPU executes code which you made.
This code tells the CPU how to **treat** the few bytes at a certain memory, like "take the four bytes at address 0x87367, treat them as an integer and add one to the value".

See, it's you who decide how to treat the memory.

Comment: You should have come up with aligned address :) </pedant>

Answer (score 1):

In general the CPU by itself knows nothing about the interpretation of values stored at certain memory locations, it's the code that is run (generated, in this case, by the compiler) that it's supposed to know it and use the correct CPU instructions to manipulate such values.

To say it in another way, the type of a variable is an abstraction of the language that tells to the compiler what code to generate to manipulate the memory.

Types in some way *do* exist at machine code level: there are various instructions to work on various types - i.e. the way the raw values stored in memory are interpreted, but it's up to the code executed to use the correct instructions to treat the values stored in memory correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking a question about CPU design?

Each CPU machine instruction is encoded so that the CPU knows how many bits to operate on.

The C++ compiler knows to emit 8-bit instructions for `char` and 32-bit instructions for `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has table which named "symbols table", so the compiler know which type is every var and how it should regard it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the architecture.  Most systems use [IEEE 754 Floating Point Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Character_representation) and [Two's Compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) for integer values, but it's up to the CPU in question.  It knows how to turn those bytes into "values" appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

On the CPU side, this mostly relates to two things: the registers and the instruction set (look at [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) for example).

The [register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) is just a small chunk of memory that is closest to the CPU. Values are put there and used there for doing basic operations.

The instruction set will include a set of fixed names (like EAX, AX, etc.) for addressing memory slots on the register. Depending on the name, they can refer to shorter or longer slots (e.g. 8 bits, 16, 32, 64, etc.). Corresponding to those registers, there are operations (like addition, multiplication, etc.) which act on register values of certain size too. How the CPU actually executes the instructions or even stores the registers is not relevant (it's at the discretion of the manufacturer of the CPU), and it's up to the programmer (or compiler) to use the instruction set correctly.

The CPU itself has no idea what it's doing (it's not "intelligent") it just does the operations as they are requested. The compiler is the one which keeps track of the types of the variables and makes sure that the instructions that are generated and later executed by the program correspond to what you have coded (that's called "compilation"). But once the program is compiled, the CPU doesn't "keep track" of the types or sizes or anything like that (it would be too expensive to do so). Since compilers are pretty much guaranteed to produce instructions that are consistent, this is not an issue. Of course, if you programmed your own code in assembly and used mismatching registers and instructions, the CPU still wouldn't care, it would just make you program behave very weird (likely to crash).

Answer (score 0):

Internally, a CPU may be wired to fetch 32 bits for an integer, which translates into 4 8-bit octets (bytes).  The CPU does not regard the fetch as 4 bytes, but rather 32 bits.

The CPU is also internally wired to fetch 8 bits for a character (byte).  In many processor architectures, the CPU fetches 32 bits from memory and internally ignores the unused bits (keeping the lowest 8 bits).  This simplifies the processor architecture by only requiring fetches of 32 bits.

In efficient platforms, the memory is also accessible in 32-bit quantities.  The data flow from the memory to the processor is often called the *databus*.  In this description it would be *32 bits wide*.

Other processor architectures can fetch 8 bits for a character.  This removes the need for the processor to ignore 3 bytes from a 32-bit fetch.

Some programmers view integers in widths of bytes rather than bits.  Thus a 32-bit integer would be thought of as 4 bytes.  This can create confusion especially with bit ordering, a.k.a. Endianess.  Some processors have the first byte containing the most significant bits (Big Endian), while others have the first byte representing the least significant bits (Little Endian).  This leads to problems when transferring binary data between platforms.

Knowing that a processor's integer can hold 4 bytes and that it fetches 4 bytes at a time, many programmers like to pack 4 characters into an integer to improve performance.  Thus the processor would require 1 fetch for 4 characters rather than 4 fetches for 4 characters.  This performance improvement may be wasted by the execution time required to pack and unpack the characters from the integer.

In summary, I highly suggest you forget about how many bytes make up an integer and any relationship to a quantity of characters or bytes.  This concept is only relevant on a few embedded platforms or a few high performance applications.  Your objective is to deliver correct and robust code within a given duration.  Performance and size concerns are at the end of a project, only tended if somebody complains.  You will do fine in your career if you concentrate on the range and limitations of an integer rather than how much memory it occupies.